# WPF: UserControl with Expander leave blank space after Expander collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have UserControl with Expander. And I use it in main window in ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

After form loaded UserControls fill space normally.

After child user control expanded parent container's height grows, as expected.
[After child user control expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqtQw.png)

If I collapsed UserControl, there are the blank space left in the parent container.
[Blank space left after child user control collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGL2U.png)

If main window gets resize event, all blank space are gone.

I'd tried use Element.InvalidateVisual and Element.InvalidateMeasure in code, and also UpdateLayout, and wrap ListBox with DockPanel + DockPanel.Dock="Top" for panel's child. It was not effect.

At other hand, when I add the same UserControl in the code, this artefact disappears: parent control collapsed as I need after child UserControl collapsed. But I need exactly XAML and UserControl as DataTemplate.

Please, help me. I sure there must be some easy solution, but I'm new to the XAML and so I have difficulty with this.

Comment: Can you include the usercontrol xaml which has the expander?

Comment: @mathew-jibin the code is:<code>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto">
<Expander>
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:MyUserControl />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox></code>

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i've solved this problem. The solution is set **ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll** property of **ListBox** element to **True**.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the parent `FrameworkElement` with a `HorizontalAligment` like in the following example.

```
<StackPanel Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Expander>
            <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SomeUserControl></local:SomeUserControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

This works on my solution.

Your FrameworkElements behaviour around your expander is a bit weird. If you still have some issues you should show more information about it.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. Expander is inside user control, not parent. Each listbox's item is presented as my user control. I'll give my markup here later, if needed.

Comment: Finally, i've solved this problem. The solution is set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll property of ListBox element to True.